# esp_timer not found while build LVGL for ESP32

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf, lvgl

Trying to build LVGL port to ESP32 demo project and flash to `WT32-SC01 PLUS With 3.5 inch 320X480` module with `ESP32-S3-WROVER` chip. I'm using `ESP-IDF V5`.

```
idf.py set-target esp32s3
idf.py build
```

Got several errors:

```
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c: In function 'guiTask':
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:144:11: error: unknown type name 'esp_timer_create_args_t'
  144 |     const esp_timer_create_args_t periodic_timer_args = {
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:145:9: error: field name not in record or union initializer
  145 |         .callback = &lv_tick_task,
      |         ^
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:145:9: note: (near initialization for 'periodic_timer_args')
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:145:21: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'void (*)(void *)' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  145 |         .callback = &lv_tick_task,
      |                     ^
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:145:21: note: (near initialization for 'periodic_timer_args')
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:146:9: error: field name not in record or union initializer
  146 |         .name = "periodic_gui"
      |         ^
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:146:9: note: (near initialization for 'periodic_timer_args')
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:146:17: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  146 |         .name = "periodic_gui"
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:146:17: note: (near initialization for 'periodic_timer_args')
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:148:5: error: unknown type name 'esp_timer_handle_t'
  148 |     esp_timer_handle_t periodic_timer;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/esp_intr_alloc.h:11,
                 from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/esp_cpu.h:20,
                 from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/spinlock.h:11,
                 from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/include/freertos/portmacro.h:74,
                 from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include/freertos/portable.h:58,
                 from C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include/freertos/FreeRTOS.h:70,
                 from C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:16:
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:149:21: error: implicit declaration of function 'esp_timer_create' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  149 |     ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_create(&periodic_timer_args, &periodic_timer));
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:117:30: note: in definition of macro 'ESP_ERROR_CHECK'
  117 |         esp_err_t err_rc_ = (x);                                        \
      |                              ^
C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32_esp_idf_5/main/main.c:150:21: error: implicit declaration of function 'esp_timer_start_periodic' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  150 |     ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_start_periodic(periodic_timer, LV_TICK_PERIOD_MS * 1000));
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:117:30: note: in definition of macro 'ESP_ERROR_CHECK'
  117 |         esp_err_t err_rc_ = (x);                                        \
      |                              ^
```

How to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what project you are talking about, but according to the error message, it can't find the esp_timer API functions.

For newer ESP-IDF versions, you have to add "esp_timer" to the REQUIRES list in CMakeLists.txt  ([reference](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v5.0/esp32s2/migration-guides/release-5.x/build-system.html#specify-component-requirements-explicitly))

i.e. main/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(srcs
    "main.c"
)

set(reqs
    "esp_timer"
)

idf_component_register(
    SRCS ${srcs}
    INCLUDE_DIRS ""
    REQUIRES ${reqs}
)
```